# Curl login user to external website

Tags: php, curl, single-sign-on

yesterday i asked o complex question about it but noone answer it so i want to ask as simply i can.

I want to login user to site b when he logs in site a. ( i want to somekind sso wordpress->lms platform)

im trying to do it with cURL and i use code like this:

```
$username="..."; 
$password="..."; 
$url="..."; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "login=".$username."&password=".$password; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
```

This script works fine but i have 2 issues:
- script redirect me to a siteB and log me in but when i click on some link in siteb i get info im not loged in ( i fink that cURL is loging in the server not user). I guess here i need to read cookie from txt file and add it to user browser ?

- i need to do it in background. So user is not redirected to site b after login on site A.
  (is curl a good option to do it?)

If anyone was doing something similar please point me in a right direction becouse im stuck on this for 2 days ;(

Here is a link to my previous answer where i explained this case in details:

[Wordpress SSO with Chamilo LMS - log in to chamilo in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862805/wordpress-sso-with-chamilo-lms-log-in-to-chamilo-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a cookie on behalf of another person for a different domain using a non-browser plugin.

Think about it for a bit... you go to a website and they log you into your bank account w/o showing you that they've done so... how would you feel?  Browser security makes that extremely difficult on purpose.

Comment: I understand that but wordpress and elearning platform will work on same domain - they are two separate websites but working in a same domain. for example. wordpress will be example.com and platform will be example.com/platform/ or platform.example.com

Comment: In that case, you'll want them to have different session ID's and set the proper cookie for the respective session id.

Comment: They should have diffrent sessions id becouse of two diffrent script (wordpress,chamilo)